# How to fix "UPDATE <table> OUTPUT WITH (READPAST)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

We are trying to retrieve and update the TOP X events from a table but without locking anything else than the "processed" rows. We looked into different SQL hints like ROWLOCK and READPAST, but haven't figured out what combination of those should be used in this scenario. Also, we need to make sure that the returned rows are unique across different concurrent executions of that query and that the same row will never be selected twice.

Note: This table has got many INSERTs happening concurrently.

```sql
UPDATE TOP(:batchSize) wsns WITH (READPAST) 
 SET consumer_ip = :consumerIP 
 OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.another_id, inserted.created_time, inserted.scheduled_time 
 FROM table_A a
 WHERE a.scheduled_time < GETUTCDATE() AND a.consumer_ip IS NULL
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite follow how/why are you trying to use the `READPAST` hint here? 
But anyway - to achieve what you want I would suggest:

```
WITH xxx AS
(
SELECT TOP(:batchSize) * 
FROM table_A
)
UPDATE xxx
SET consumer_ip = :consumerIP 
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.another_id, inserted.created_time, inserted.scheduled_time 
FROM table_A a
WHERE a.scheduled_time < GETUTCDATE() AND a.consumer_ip IS NULL;
```

If all that could happen in the background are new inserts then, I can't see why this would be a problem. SQL Server optimiser  most likely would decide for PAGE/ROW lock (but this is depending on your DB settings as well as indexes affected and their options). If by any reason you want to stop other transaction until this update is finished - hold an exclusive lock on the entire table, till the end of your transaction, you can just add `WITH(TABLOCKX)`. Therefore, I would strongly recommend to have a good read on the SQL Server concurrency and isolation before you start messing with it in a production environment.